# Php errors not logging for wordpress plugins

Tags: php, wordpress, error-logging

When I have a php error in a wordpress plugin or theme on my localhost, it doesn't output to my Apache error log.

This is not the case for php files that I have in my www/ directory; those seem to log just fine, as do errors from the wordpress core.  This also seems to be the case on other servers as well.

Any thoughts as to what might be causing this?

Answer (score 4):

As the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) says:

> `WP_DEBUG_LOG` is companion to `WP_DEBUG` that causes all errors to also be saved to a `debug.log` log file inside the `/wp-content/` directory. This is useful if you want to review all notices later or need to view notices generated off-screen (e.g. during an AJAX request or `wp-cron` run).

Edit your `wp-config.php` file and add the following definition (if not already present):

```
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
```

This will make Wordpress log the errors to `/wp-content/debug.log`.

However, if you want to change the location of the `debug.log` file, you can use the following work-around:

```
if (defined('WP_DEBUG_LOG') && WP_DEBUG_LOG) {
    ini_set( 'error_log', WP_CONTENT_DIR.'/foo/debug.log' ); //modify accordingly
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply!  I added define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true); just under my define('WP_DEBUG', true);  and it's not outputting anything to debug.log.  I should also add that, when it comes to plugin errors, I also don't get any error message on my browser, despite having wp_debug enabled.  To get a better idea of what was going on, I installed a fresh version of wordpress, broke a plugin, and found that the error message was both printed in my apache error.log and on my browser window, regardless of debugging settings.